# Use a return value of a C++ program in an R script

Tags: c++, r, return-value

The result of a simulation, written in C++, is stored as a double during runtime. Now I like to use this double in a R script to analyse if the variation of one run compared to another is ok.
Since I'm not allowed to return a double form `main` I do currently following:

```
//...
cout<<D<<endl; //D is my double containing the simulation result
return 0 };
```

I call the program 10 times form my R script and like to store the value of D in an R-vector (also called D).

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  D[i] <- as.numeric(system("./program"))
}
```

However, D will be filled with the return values of the C++ program, thus 10 zeros. Can I somehow use the value of `cout` instead? Or is there a better way to communicate?

Please note, I look for a simple light-weight solution on a Linux machine.

Comment: Just `cout` the output and use `system("./program", intern=TRUE)` to capture the output from the `system` call.

Comment: Your are right, this works. I actually tired it before but set the braces at the wrong place -.-". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seriously if you are concerning the communication between R and c++, you should consider use Rcpp (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html), and particularly, read the Rcpp Attributes (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) which gives very clear step by step approach.